# regexp-to-DFA algorithm

Tags: regex, lexer, dfa

I'm writing a regexp-based lexical analyzer generator based on a regexp-to-DFA direct translation algorithm described in the Dragon Book.

It calculates the `nullable`, `firstpos`, `lastpos`, and `followpos` functions for concatenation, alternation, and kleene-star nodes. I want to add quantifiers for `+` (one or more times) and `?` (zero or one time).

`nullable`, `firstpos`, and `lastpos` are easy to calculate, but I'm not sure about `followpos`. Is it better to not implement those quantifiers as part of the parsing stage, and instead rewrite it in the lexical analysis stage (I think this is only "syntactic sugar" to kleene-star and alternation)?